# Even if, IF condition is false why statement executes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my code,

`columnLength = tColumns.length;`

```
    if (parseInt(columnLength) ==2) {
        tColumns[0].parentNode.insertBefore(tD, tColumns[0].nextSibling);
    }
    if (parseInt(columnLength) >= 3) 
    {
        tColumns[0].parentNode.insertBefore(tD, tColumns[0].nextSibling);
        tColumns[0].parentNode.insertAfter(tD, tColumns[0].nextSibling);
    }`
```

Suppose columnLength is **1**.. 1st **IF** condition is false and its not executing the inside statements.

Even 2nd condition is false since **1 is not greater than equals to 3**, but the statements are being executed!

What is wrong with the code?

I'm using Visual Studio IDE to debug, even in immediate window also **IF condition returns false** as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Is the prime at the end of the second if statement meant to be there?

Comment: It might not fix the problem, but you should always supply a second parameter to `parseInt` i.e. `parseInt(columnLength, 10)` - the **radix** parameter is important.

Comment: Consider `if.. else if..else`

Comment: jsFiddle or the problem doesn't exist ;)

Comment: Conor Pender - No, Typo

Comment: Since you're using `==` therefore I think there is no need to parse it

Comment: Please prepare a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that we can run and debug.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually executing?  put a `console.log(columnLength)` within each block and explicitly verify that it's running

Comment: Have you checked the actual value of `tColumns.length`? [This fiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/fCCP3/).

Comment: How is tColumns defined ?

Comment: Are you sure tColumns.length is not undefined?

Comment: When you do find the solution, you should post it here to help anybody else who comes across this problem... and to stop people asking questions about it.

Comment: tColumns.length is defined and its value is **1** as specified in the example. Problem still not solved :(

Comment: @user2729272 In my opinion: the only possibility is that your IDE lies to you. If the condition is `false` JavaScript **will not** enter the `if` block. Have you actually checked that the thing you are trying to do does not happen in browser?

Comment: It's nasty code but could you do the following?? `if ( (parseInt(columnLength, 10) === 2) === true) { alert("something"); }`

Comment: Tried all the suggestions! Still wonder what is wrong with the code :(

Comment: It did or didn't alert? If it did,, then we require your code in JSFiddle, if it didn't ur problem is solved.

Comment: It did alert! tColumns.length is **1** over here

Comment: Could you past the code on JSFiddle please?

Comment: @user2729272 Recreate the relevant piece of code, put in jsFiddle and show us. Otherwise you are telling us something that is clearly impossible. One more time: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or it doesn't exist. P.S. How do you know that `tColumns.length` is `1`? Try doing `alert(tColumns.length);` inside the snippet that larssy1 proposed.

Comment: Maybe a very dumb idea, but: Are you sure that parseInt is really the parseInt that you want and not an other function that you wrote with some weird side-effects?

Comment: works fine with jsFiddle with same condition having sample values! I found a weird solution wch worked! I negated the IF statement  ` if (!parseInt(columnLength) >= 3) 
    {` This worked for me! But can some explain me why is this happening :(

Answer (score 0):

ONTOPIC :

I assume your tColumns.length might not have the value you expect it to have. I guess it has the value of undefined which can not be parsed as an integer.

http://jsfiddle.net/FRXkM/1/

OFFTOPIC :

Might not be related to your problem. But parseInt requires a second parameter in conventional ways.

For example:

```
parseInt("34", 10);
```

For info on parseInt and its parameters go to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: But he mentions that the if statement returns false.

Comment: As i stated at the top of my answer :'] Also i included a jsfiddle which is related..

Comment: @larssy1 Then instead of posting it as an answer you should post it as a comment.

Comment: @larssy1 It is still unrelated. OP clearly says "but the statements are being executed" even though the condition is `false`. In case when you can't parse it you would receive `NaN` which yields `false`: `NaN != 2`. Not to mention that he clearly states that `.length` is 1.

Comment: Ye, i know about the returned value :) I noticed his "but the statements are being executed" too late since I was messing around in JSFiddle, my apoligies.

Comment: The W3S link clearly says a second parameter is optional, but you say it's required. Since it defaults to 10, it's not needed.

Comment: With conventional ways I mean code validation. Validation services like JSLint require a second parameter for this function.